# Raid system fails to boot after moving from 2.6 kernel to 3.5

Tags: linux, raid, kernel, gentoo, linux-kernel

I'm running Gentoo Linux with a custom compiled kernel and I've just migrated from a 2.6 kernel to a 3.5.

As my HD's are on RAID 0 mode I use a custom initrd file in order to be able to boot. While kernel 2.6 is able to boot without problems the new 3.5 compiled kernel fails to boot complaining about `no block devices found`. After taking a look at `initrd.cpio` contained scripts I can see the failure message is given by `mdadm` tool.

Does anyone has a clue about that?

Edit: 
this morning i noticed there was some kind of issue on my old initrd which works fine for 2.6 kernels, so created a new initrd which works fine and let me to boot into GNU/Gentoo Linux with same 3.5 bzImage.

It could be an issue of mdadm, gonna check it.

```
https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=416081
```

Comment: Did you also update the rest of your system? BTW, you would probably have better luck getting an answer on the gentoo-users mailing list.

Answer (score 0):

A new kernel usually requires a new initrd.

With the generated (genkernel) initrd, there is the `scandelay=<seconds>` boot parameter which has proven helpful to me in the past. On one of my boxes, mdadm ran before all devices were available and failed to assemble the /dev/mdX device where the root partition resides.

If I understand correctly (from looking at `/usr/share/genkernel/defaults/initrd.scripts`), scandelay forces the script to hang around while udev to settles, before assembling any software arrays and before trying to mount the real root partition.

Try a scandelay of 3-10 seconds.